# Activate a tool using enumproperty (menu list, icons only)

Tags: python, blender, bpy, custom-ui

[image: image of the menu]

I'm delving down the blender python coding and I want to do a custom menu using `enum`. I want this menu to activate the corresponding tool I included inside this list.

A good example I want to imitate is the viewport shading menu on the right hand side of the 3d viewport where you click the icons(see picture above)

I really like this interface unlike the toolbar on the left side.

I was successful already displaying the menu (see picture above) but its effectively NOT WORKING because I don't know where I should put the functions inside of

Godspeed please!
Thank you in advance

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.